# Video content: missing plugins

Tags: codecs

I can't play any video content.
I keep getting errors about missing plugins. I installed the 3rd party codecs at install.

I am getting the following error

```
No packages with the requested plugins found
```

The requested plugins are:

```
GStreamer element ffmux_dvd
GStreamer element ffdeinterlace
```

When I look in Ubuntu Software centre all of the Gstreamer plugins appear to be installed and the only option is to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.*` worked for me.

With the `s` on the end (as in [Danial Jose's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/236945/22949)), it wouldn't work. I replaced the `s` with an asterix (`*`) and it worked; if you have the same problem, this may fix it for you. (Tested 3 different videos in Arista, a flv, an mp4 and an webm and they all work now.)

Answer (score 0):

In some countries, the use of the below unlicensed decryption software is not permitted by law. Verify that you are within your rights to use it.

Install **libdvdnav4**, **libdvdread4**, **gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad**, and **gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly**.

If you would like to play encrypted DVDs (see the legal note above), open the Dash and launch a Terminal.

Type the following into the screen which appears, then press Enter:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Enter your password to complete the installation.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this was unsuccessful. According to Ubuntu software centre all of these packages are installed. I ran the suggested commend I get "command not found"

Comment: The and of the command was wrong. You can try it now. But it does not solved my problem in Ubuntu 14.04. The question should include Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg) [image: Install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg].

Comment: Not available for my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this that fixed my Arista transcoder that was asking me the same thing, worked for me on Ubuntu 14.4 64bit.
Published on Apr 21, 2014

> Solución del Problema con GStreamer elemento ffdeinterlace en Arista
>   En Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>
> ### Abrir el Terminal
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
> ```