# Arista Transcoder Not Working

Tags: arista-transcoder

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I was installing and using Arista Transcoder seamlessly with no problems at all. After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 and installing Arista, whenever I try to transcode any video, the following error message appears

```
Python2.7-minimal requires an additional plugin for this operation.
The following plugin is required:
GStreamer element ffdeinterlance
Do you want to search for this now?
```

When I press "Search", the following error message appears:

```
Cannot add conversion to queue because of missing elements!
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: BUG: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arista/+bug/571910   dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/236910/video-content-missing-plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg. It is, however, not available in the 14.04 repositories, so you can get it from a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```