# Arista transcoder not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dvd, arista-transcoder

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. I want to convert an mp4 file to the Video_TS/Audio_TS format for DVDs. After adding the file and starting the application, I get a message that a required element is missing, and it asks to search. After searching, the displayed message says missing element cannot be found. I don't know what is missing, or how to fix this. I already tried the suggestion previously made for Ubuntu 14.04 ([Arista Transcoder Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452282/arista-transcoder-not-working)), which did not solve the problem. Can someone either suggest a fix, or point me to a another transcoder that will help?

Comment: What is the missing element?

Comment: @nicled download links are not available? how can i download it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found the answer.
Here is an updated PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```